# Error: "response":"X006","description":"Invalid hash"

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I made a call with Restsharp with the following code in Gridview row command in ASP.net C#:

```
const string task = "pay";
const string command_api_token = "D3Kc4vMatqQ7pQtU39D22j35aKqy8";
const string merchant_email_on_voguepay = "abc@wyz.com";

                Random rnd = new Random();
                string refl = DateTime.Now + rnd.Next(1, 9999999).ToString();
                byte[] hash_target = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(command_api_token + task + merchant_email_on_voguepay + refl);

                string hash = BitConverter.ToString(new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(hash_target)).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToUpper();


                // //load all fields as json and serialize
                var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                         { "task", "pay"},
                         { "merchant", "1234-4567"},
                         { "ref",refl},
                         { "hash",hash},
                         { "remarks", "secure trade"},
                         { "seller", "seller@website.com"},
                         { "cur", "usd"},
                         { "amount", "20"}
                    };

           //serialization using Newtonsoft JSON
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keyValues);

          //url encode the json
           var postString = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(json);

//calling API with Restsharp
var client = new RestClient("https://voguepay.com/api/");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("json", json);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

the call returns the following error when I use the real parameters for email_on_voguepay and command_api_token.

this is what it returns:

{"response":"X006","description":"Invalid hash","values":"","salt":"58656ba1d162a","hash":"2638fb45f266d35bc78524490a3329a3fecf7b5189c473e82e45d7d6a22f07656743e2cb9ae28dfc81e77eef49eb24d46e0fd4a71cab16847a7afd225310feb5","username":"MyName"}

Please I need help here, what did I do wrong and how do I correct that?

Comment: We need the other side of your code.  I would assume the problem is it is having a problem decoding your hash value.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be your request has a invalid hash (token). I suggest you to check the `string refl = DateTime.Now + rnd.Next(1, 9999999).ToString();`
The time function in php (according with voguePay API, returns the unix timestamp.

So in C# please consider using `DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds`  or `(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds`

For more info, please consider checking the generated token was following instructions:

Required Security code generated by **concatenating** the following and passing the result through a **sha512** encryption
*your command api token*
*task specified above*
*your voguepay email*
*ref specified above*

*ref    Unique id for each request (Required)   $field['ref'] = time().mt_rand(0,999999999);*

https://voguepay.com/developers

Comment: I tried using (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds,and followed the instruction for generating token using my specified voguepay parameters, but still get the same error message.

Comment: try this:
`ref = string.Format("{0}{1}", (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds, new Random().Next(0,9999999));`